# convert integer to 24 hours :DB2-sql

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a table with integer  values. I need to convert the integer value into 24 hour format,how i can do it i tried to use FOM/60 but it gives fel result

```
From          ------------ what i want to se
570                          9:30               
600                          10:00
700                          11:40
1020                         17:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Using time type you can just add minutes to midnight

```
with table1 (val) as (values 570, 600, 700, 1020, 1234)
select time('00:00') + val minutes from table1
```

Comment: as magic !!!!!!!!!!!thanks this  site learn me so  much !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this snipets:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
  Num INTEGER 
);
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (570);
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (600);
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (700);
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (1020);

SELECT cast(Num/60 as nvarchar)+':'+right ('00'+ltrim(str( Num%60 )),2 ) FROM numbers
```

Output:

```
9:30
10:00
11:40
17:00
```